# Access only by network name

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a win server 2003 on my network, I cannot access a web service on that server using local IP or real live IP, only I can use the network name .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of madness

As far as I understand, The client was detecting a proxy and was trying to connect through it.
simply don't use proxy at the client.

but I am still don't get it, why it woks fine with HTTP and failed to work with HTTPS.  HTTPS works only when those lines is added.

Someone try to explain this to me!!

ASP.net

```
 IWebProxy myProxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
 GlobalProxySelection.Select = myProxy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your web site is configured to only accept requests for a given name; you should have a look at your IIS configuration.

Does the web service run in the default web site or in a custom one?
How are site bindings configured?

Comment: It runs in the custom one, more over the rest of websites does not have that madness !!